# Akka Typed - How to sent Terminated message to BehaviorTestKit

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit, akka-typed, akka-actor

I'm trying to unit test my actor's handling of a "Terminated" message for a child actor.  The code under test is something like this:

```
    case Terminated(terminatedActor) =>
      val actorName = terminatedActor.path.name
      if (actorName.startsWith("ChildActor")) {
        doSomething()
      }
      Behaviors.same
```

In my unit test, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    val testInbox = TestInbox[ParentActor.Request](name = "ChildActor1")
    val testKit = BehaviorTestKit(ParentActor())
    testKit.run(Terminated(testInbox.ref))
    assert( *** that doSomething() happened *** )
```

The unit test code doesn't compile.  I get this error in the call to testKit.run():

type mismatch;
found   : akka.actor.typed.Terminated
required: ParentActor.Request

I assume that this is because the Terminated message does not inherit from my ParentActor.Request trait.

Based on a below comment, I changed the unit test to:

```
    val testInbox = TestInbox[ParentActor.Request](name = "ChildActor1")
    val testKit = BehaviorTestKit(ParentActor())
    testKit.signal(Terminated(testInbox.ref))
    assert( *** that doSomething() happened *** )
```

This now compiles, but the call to testKit.signal() now throws a DeathPactException, which the docs say means that the actor is not handling the Terminated message, even though my production code definitely does handle it.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: use `testKit.signal(Terminated(ref))` instead of .run

Comment: @AminMal Thanks.  This compiles.  However, it now throws a DeathPactException, which the docs say means that the actor is not handling the Terminated message, even though my production code definitely does handle it.  Any idea why?

Comment: I just read the docs again and found out that `BehaviorTestKit.signal(...)` sends the signal to the **BehaviorTestKit** and not the actor living inside the test kit. So that's where we're going wrong. Let me do a quick look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your production code definitely handles the `Terminated` signal?

Signals are not, from the perspective of a typed `Behavior`, messages.  They are processed by the signal handler installed by `receiveSignal`.  That signal handler takes not just the signal but the `ActorContext` as well, wrapped up in a tuple.  If the response to a `Terminated` signal doesn't require the context, you still have to match against it:

```scala
// inside a .receiveSignal...
case (_, Terminated(terminatedActor)) =>
  val actorName = terminatedActor.path.name
  if (actorName.startsWith("ChildActor")) {
    doSomething()
  }
  Behaviors.same
```

Note that Akka's test suite includes [this test which exercises handling the `Terminated` signal](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/00c1da99448e1138ac154e0f13bada0d5c38c5f8/akka-actor-testkit-typed/src/test/scala/akka/actor/testkit/typed/scaladsl/BehaviorTestKitSpec.scala#L333) when sent via `testKit.signal`:

```scala
      val other = TestInbox[String]()
      val testkit = BehaviorTestKit[Parent.Command](Parent.init)
      noException should be thrownBy {
        testkit.signal(Terminated(other.ref))
      }
```

Comment: Ah, that was it!  I didn't realize that Terminated had to be received via receiveSignal instead of receiveMessage.  Thanks for the reference to testkit.signal() also.  Worked beautifully.